# How to add New Post On clicking a button?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have a custom post type name `guide_tutorial`.As I add new post  It creates a  button name `Add Pointer`.On clicking the `Add pointer` button its open a popup which have details about pointer .Now I want that on clicking  `Add' button it create a new post.How to do that ? Here is my screen[image] shot of what I have done.

Comment: So is the Pointer acting like a category? The Tutorial is like a post? A bit hard to tell how it works. Creating a separate Pointer custom post type might be one way to get the default 'add' behaviour? I don't understand the relationship between Tutorials and Pointers so it's difficult to advise - please explain.

Comment: Considering that is a form within the popup, use [`wp_insert_post($args)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) to insert the post on submit, in the args set `post_type` to your CPT name and set other necessary elements. You could use AJAX with this one and you should consult How to use AJAX with plugins in the codex..

Comment: You could use the WordPress REST API that enables to do CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) with AJAX calls and JSON.